# Error: Expected expression before structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to return a pointer to a structure but I keep getting this weird error `bboard.c:35: error: Expecte expression before 'BBoard'` Does anyone have any ideas on to what could be causing this. I fairly new in c so my apologies of this is a trivial question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "bboard.h"

struct BBoard {
int create[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
};


BBoard * bb_create(int nrows, int ncols){
int i,j;
srand(time(NULL));
struct BBoard Bboard;
for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
        int r = rand() % 4;
        //printf("%d",r);

        if( r == 0){ 
        Bboard.create[i][j] = 1;}
        if(r == 1){
        Bboard.create[i][j] = 2;}
        if(r == 2){ 
        Bboard.create[i][j] = 3;}
        if(r == 3){
        Bboard.create[i][j] = 4;}
        printf(" %d ",Bboard.create[i][j]);
            }
        printf("\n");
        }
struct BBoard *boardPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct BBoard));
if (boardPtr != NULL){
//printf("%d",boardPtr->create[1][1]);
return BBoard *boardPtr;
}
else{
printf("Error");
}
}

/**extern void bb_display(BBoard *b){
int i,j;
BBoard Bboard = b;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        printf("%d",Bboard.create[i][j]);
        }
    }
}**/


int main(){
BBoard *bptr;
bptr = bb_create(5,5);
//printf("%d",bptr->create[0][1]);
}
```

Comment: this line: struct BBoard Bboard; 1) setting instance names to the same as a struct name, (capitalization aside) is very bad practice. 2) the code is returning a pointer to this struct, where the struct is on the stack.  Such a technique as returning a pointer to an item on the stack leads to undefined behaviour because once the stack goes out of scope (in this case by exiting the program.) the contents of the stack is undefined.  suggest struct BBoard * myBBoard = malloc( sizeof struct BBoard );  then return myBBoard;

Comment: the latest code is returning the variable boardptr however, there is nothing set in that allocated memory

Comment: your code has the correct method of defining a struct type.  other possibilities, like typedef, are obsolete and or depreciated.

Comment: @user3629249: Why do you think that `typedef` is obsolete or deprecated (note spelling)?

Answer (score 3):

In C, you need to use `struct BBoard` until you've used:

```
typedef struct BBoard BBoard;
```

In C++, you don't need to create the typedef.

---

> Could you elaborate a litle bit? I dont understand.

You have:

```
struct BBoard
{
    int create[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
};


BBoard * bb_create(int nrows, int ncols)
{
    …
```

The structure definition creates a type `struct BBoard`.  It does not create a type `BBoard`; it only creates `struct BBoard`.  So, when you next write `BBoard *bb_create`, there isn't a type `BBoard`, so the compiler complains.

If you write one of these sequences — either:

```
typedef struct BBoard
{
    int create[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
} BBoard;
```

or:

```
typedef struct BBoard BBoard;
struct BBoard
{
    int create[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
};
```

or:

```
struct BBoard
{
    int create[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
};
typedef struct BBoard BBoard;
```

then you both define a type `struct BBoard` and an alias for the type `BBoard` and then your code will compile.

In C++, simply defining a `struct` or `class` defines a type which can be used without the `struct` or `class` prefix.

---

If your code compiled past the start of the function definition, then (a) you aren't using a standard C compiler, and (b) you have problems further down your code at:

```
return BBoard *boardPtr;
```

Since this is part of:

```
    struct BBoard *boardPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct BBoard));
    if (boardPtr != NULL){
        //printf("%d",boardPtr->create[1][1]);
        return BBoard *boardPtr;
    }
    else{
        printf("Error");
    }
}
```

You really don't need to cast the return type at all, but if you think you do, you should use proper cast notation (one of these two, preferably the first):

```
        return boardPtr;
        return (BBoard *)boardPtr;
```

The error message in the `else` clause should be more informative, should end with a new line, should be written to standard error, and should be followed by a `return 0;` or equivalent.

Comment: @leffler Could You elaborate a litle bit? I dont understand.